# Trying to POST data from my android application to a php file on a server but data is always null. Why

Tags: java, php, android

The post variable is never being set and for now, all I'm trying to do is set that variable but it's always null

All my credentials are correct and I am accessing the the php file but just unable to post any data at all. Could this be a problem on my server?

This is my java code:

```
try {

            URL url = new URL("http://ggh.com/ghh.php");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setReadTimeout(15 * 1000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15 * 1000);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setDoInput(true);

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();

            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));

            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                    .appendQueryParameter("password", password)
                    .appendQueryParameter("username", username);
            String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

            bufferedWriter.write(query);

            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            os.close();

            conn.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
            String line = "";

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                response += line;
            }
            try {
                objmain = new JSONObject(response);
                jsonArray = objmain.getJSONArray("apps");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                    obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    pass = (obj.getString("password"));
                    pass_hash = (obj.getString("password_hash"));
                    first_name = (obj.getString("first_name"));
                    last_name = (obj.getString("last_name"));
                    email_personal = (obj.getString("email_personal"));
                    phone_personal = (obj.getString("phone_personal"));
                    linkedin = (obj.getString("linkedin"));
                    company_name = (obj.getString("company_name"));
                    job_title = (obj.getString("job_title"));
                    phone_professional = (obj.getString("phone_professional"));
                    email_professional = (obj.getString("email_professional"));
                    address = (obj.getString("address"));
                    database = username + "_db";

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            conn.disconnect();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

My php code:

```
<?php

$servername = "sad.com";
$username = "ad";
$password = "adad";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

mysqli_select_db($conn,"connkt");

function hashPassword($password, $salt) {
$hash_password = hash("SHA512", base64_encode(str_rot13(hash("SHA512",    str_rot13($salt . $password)))));
return $hash_password;
}


$user = $_POST['username'];  

$pass = $_POST['password'];

$hashed_password = hashPassword('someday', $pass);

$response["apps"] = array();

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "Select * FROM `users` WHERE username='$user'   LIMIT 1");

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$apps = array();

  $apps["password"] = $row["password"];
  $apps["first_name"] = $row["first_name"];
  $apps["last_name"] = $row["last_name"];
  $apps["email_personal"] = $row["email_personal"];
  $apps["facebook"] = $row["facebook"];
  $apps["phone_personal"] = $row["phone_personal"];
  $apps["linkedin"] = $row["linkedin"];
  $apps["company_name"] = $row["company"];
  $apps["job_title"] = $row["title"];
  $apps["phone_professional"] = $row["phone_professional"];
  $apps["email_professional"] = $row["email_professional"];
  $apps["address"] = $row["address"];
  $apps["password_hash"] = $hashed_password;

  array_push($response["apps"], $apps);
}
print(json_encode($user));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Volley to send data to the server :

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/